# Calculating AIC

Tags: aic

I have following data

```
Model 1: Y ∼ B1 + B2 + B3 + B4: log L = −213.4
Model 2: Y ∼ B1 + B2 + B3 + B5: log L = −567.1
```

The question that i have is "Calculate AIC for these 2 models". It doesn't say much. I know the formula for AIC is

$$
AIC = -2log(L) + 2p
$$

Based on this, is the solution for `Model 1` is literally `-2 * -213.4 = 2 * 4` ? I don't think that it would be that simple. Also, how would i know which one to pick based on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming one of your B's is the intercept, then your `p` is correct. The `p` captures the number of parameters in the model, including the intercept. It looks like you have a typo in your formula though. The `=` should be `+`.

To choose between the models, compare the AIC scores. Choose the model with the lower AIC score.

Comment: Error variance is another parameter that is being estimated. I think it should be included in the parameter count. For these two models, ithat would not change which AIC is lower, though.